# SMS Gateway Design Fast2SMS

Tags: php, wordpress, mobile, sms, sms-gateway

Friends I am using http://www.fast2sms.com for Sending Bulk SMS. But Now I want to send a welcome SMS and confirmation SMS to every new subscriber. I am using a WordPress Website. Fast2SMS provided me an API:

> http://api.fast2sms.com/sms.php?token=&mob=&mess=&sender=SONIIN&route=0

```
token=  Your UNIQUE TOKEN ID
mob= 10 Digit Indian Mobile Number
mess= 145 Character (English only)
sender= 6 Digit Sender ID
route=0- NonDND  &  1- DND
```

Please Tell Me How to use it and if possible then tell me how to build it in my WordPress admin panel

Comment: you can make plugin for this.In plugin add hook like https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register

Answer (score 2):

This is accepting a get request so ...

```
$token = "1SDJGWEH";
$mob = "7855212520";
$msg = "HELLO";
$sender = "Hola";

$url = "http://api.fast2sms.com/sms.php?token=".$token."&mob=".$mob."&mess=".$msg."&sender=".$sender."&route=0";

$resp = file_get_contents($url);

print_r($resp);
```

this will work ...

to make post requests you need to use `CURL`